# Why 'map' function is showing undefined error even though it is defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am using React with NodeJS and MongoDB to integrate FE with BE. I am working on Homepage and its divided in 4 phases.

Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../Styles/Home.css';
import HomeUH from './HomeUH';
import HomeLH from './HomeLH';
class Home extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state={
            cities: [],
            widgets: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount()
    {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4005/api/locationDD')
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                cities: result.data.locations
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

        axios.get('http://localhost:4005/api/widget')
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                widgets: result.data.widget
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
    render()
    {
        const { cities, widgets } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <HomeUH cities={cities}/>    
                <HomeLH widgets={widgets}/>    
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

HomeUH.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../Styles/Home.css';
import homewall from '../Images/homewall.jpg';
class HomeUH extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }
    render()
    {
        const { cities } = this.props;
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <img className="homewall" src={homewall} height="50%" width="100%"/>
                <div className="logo">
                    Sample   
                </div>
                <div className="heading">
                    Find the best Schools & Colleges
                </div>  
                <div className="search">
                    <select className="locdd">
                        <option value="0" selected disabled>Select Location</option>
                        {
                            cities.map((city, index) => {
                                return <option value={city.city_id} key={index}>{city.name}</option>
                            })
                        }
                    </select>
                    <div style={{position: 'relative', float: 'right'}}>   
                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style={{position: 'absolute', fontSize: '2rem', top: '40px', left: '35px'}}></span>
                        <input className="restInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter School/College Name" style={{paddingLeft: '50px'}}/>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <br/><br/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default HomeUH;
```

HomeLH.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../Styles/Home.css';
import QSItem from './QSItem';
class HomeLH extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }
    render()
    {
        const { widgets } = this.props;
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <a id="heading1">Quick Searches</a> <br/>
                <a id="heading2">Discover different Colleges by Streams </a> <br/><br/>
                <div className="container-fluid" style={{minWidth: '1000px', margin: 'auto'}}>
                    <div className="row">
                        {
                            widgets.map((widget, index) => {
                               return <QSItem key={index} widget={widget}></QSItem>
                            })
                        }        
                    </div>           
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default HomeLH;
```

QSItem.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../Styles/Home.css';
class QSItem extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        const {widget} = this.props;
        const img = require(`../${widget.image}`).default;
        return(
        <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div className="card mb-3" style={{maxWidth: '540px', marginLeft: '35px'}}>
                <div className="row quicksearch" style={{paddingLeft: '1px', paddingBottom: '1px'}}>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <img className="card-img" src={img} alt="" height="100%" style={{width: '140px', margin: 'auto'}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8" style={{float: 'right'}}>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="tileheading">
                                {widget.name}
                            </div>
                            <div className="tilesubheading">
                                {widget.content}
                            </div>       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default QSItem;
```

If you see in HomeUH.js in  I applied map function for cities and it went well. But when I done same process in HomeLH.js for widget its showing error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" even though it is defined in 'widgets'.

Comment: Try adding failsafe conditions before using it, `cities  = (cities instanceof Array) ? cities : []`, and find out why its empty.

Comment: Your probably not waiting for the response of the async call. So your front end is not loading the data but you see it in console with the mention this data was just evaluated now.

Comment: @pilchard you can `.map` over an empty array just fine, it just return an empty array, that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you "override" your state with `this.setState`, You can use a callback to use previous state and merge your new value with the old state:

```js
    componentDidMount()
    {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4005/api/locationDD')
        .then(result => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                cities: result.data.locations
            }))
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

        axios.get('http://localhost:4005/api/widget')
        .then(result => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                widgets: result.data.widget
            }))
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

This should prevent your `widgets` to ever be `undefined`.

Another possible solution is to wait for both request to end before setting the data, this can be achieved with `Promise.all`:

```js
        Promise.all([
            axios.get('http://localhost:4005/api/locationDD'),
            axios.get('http://localhost:4005/api/widget'),
        ])
        .then(([locationResult, widgetResult]) => {
            this.setState({
                widgets: widgetResult.data.widget,
                cities: locationResult.data.locations
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

In this case you will only update your state once.

Comment: I tired with both the solutions but it is still showing the same error.

Comment: did you remove your previous code ?
If you log `this.state` in your `render` function of `Home.js`, is `widget` ever missing ?

Comment: I made changes in the previous code but not removed. And if I log `this.state` in `render` function, widget is not missing.

Comment: you must replace your previous code, also the log in the render function should be triggered more than once, if you always have `widgets` and `cities` then It's probably a typo I missed somewhere